# Как прочитать из файла все найденные значения по ключу?

Tags: c#

Есть файл, в нём присутствуют записи:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Smart\Goblin\Sessions\Standart%20Settings]
"HostName"="zero"
"Protocol"="spn"
"UserName"="default"
```

Мне нужно через `File.ReadAllLines` прочитать название `Standart%20Settings` и затем перечислить все найденные строчки от: `HostName`, `Protocol`, `UserName`

```
"HostName"= "zero"
"Protocol"= "spn"
"UserName"= "default"
```

Как это правильнее всего сделать?

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема? Вы можете прочитать файл (весь сразу или по мере надобности) и достать название и пары ключ-значений (чистым C#, через регулярки, своим парсером, особо не имеет значение).

Comment: А с чем проблема-то? конкретно...

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").Select(x => x.Split('=')).Where(x => x.Length > 1).ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim('"'), x => x[1].Trim('"'));`

Comment: Если это какой-то ini-файл с настройками, то можете воспользоваться кодом из ответа в вопросе по ссылке - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file

Comment: @Frehzy, нет, не ini-файл, решение aepot помогло)